# how to sequence default parameter with arbitrary parameter

Tags: python

Python expects the arbitrary arguments in the end of the parameter list, but just before that if we have default parameter with the value assigned to it.
how to pass the arguments to match the parameters. 
the question is, no arguments has to be passed for the sales_man parameter and unknown has to be printed.

```
  def pizzas(size, sales_man='unknown', *toppings):
         print(f'your order is accepted for the pizza size: {size} by {sales_man}'
               f'\nPlease check your toppings as below: ')
         for topping in toppings:
             print(f'- {topping}')


     pizzas('medium', 'cheesy', 'Bacon', 'pepporni', 'Pineapple')
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `def` to:

`def pizzas(size, *toppings, sales_man='unknown')`

Then `sales_man` can be passed as keyword argument, not positional argument:

`pizzas('medium', 'cheesy', 'Bacon', 'pepporni', 'Pineapple')`

Output:

```
your order is accepted for the pizza size: medium by unknown
Please check your toppings as below: 
- cheesy
- Bacon
- pepporni
- Pineapple
```

Input:

`pizzas('medium', 'cheesy', 'Bacon', 'pepporni', 'Pineapple', sales_man="Man")`

Output:

```
your order is accepted for the pizza size: medium by Man(...)
```

Answer (score 0):

You just can't do that. You'll have to supply that default value every time you call the function (which defeats the purpose of having the default value to start with) or move the default parameter to the end of the definition and mention it explicitly in your call, like this:

```
def a(b, *c, d=5):
    ...

a(1, 2,3,4,5, d=6)
```

Answer (score 0):

You just can't do that.  Instead You can try this ---

```
def pizzas(size, sales_man, *toppings):
  if sales_man == None:
    sales_man = 'unknown'
  print("sales_man :: " + sales_man)
  print(f'your order is accepted for the pizza size: {size} by {sales_man}'f'\nPlease check your toppings as below: ')
  for topping in toppings:
    print(f'- {topping}')

pizzas('medium', None, 'cheesy', 'Bacon', 'pepporni', 'Pineapple')
```

**Or**

Change your method signature to --- `def pizzas(size, *toppings, sales_man='unknown'):`

In case **you want to pass** **sales_man**, then you can call it as

```
pizzas('medium','cheesy', 'Bacon', 'pepporni', 'Pineapple', sales_man="Pawan")
```

or In case **you don't want to pass** **sales_man**,then you can call it as

```
pizzas('medium','cheesy', 'Bacon', 'pepporni', 'Pineapple')
```